# How can i get multiple lists as an output when i pass multiple ID's in Neo4j Cypher query?

Tags: sql, list, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

My current cypher query is as following

```
MATCH (p:xyz)-[:children *]->(c:xyz)
WHERE p.Code=100
WITH COLLECT (c) + p AS all 
UNWIND all as p MATCH (p)-[:children]->(c) 
RETURN collect(DISTINCT c.Code) as Children_Nodes
```

This gives me an output like

```
"Children_Nodes"                                                      │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[101,102,103,104,105]│
```

And if I pass two different id's like

```
MATCH (p:xyz)-[:children *]->(c:xyz)
WHERE p.Code IN [100,200]
WITH COLLECT (c) + p AS all 
UNWIND all as p MATCH (p)-[:children]->(c) 
RETURN collect(DISTINCT c.Code) as Children_Nodes
```

This will return something like

```
"Children_Nodes"                                                      │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[101,102,103,104,105,201,202,203,204,205]│
```

**But what i actually need are two different separate lists and not one collated list like above**

```
"Children_Nodes"                                                      │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[101,102,103,104,105] [201,202,203,204,205]│
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
MATCH (p:xyz)-[:children *]->(c:xyz)
WHERE p.Code IN [100,200]
WITH p, COLLECT (DISTINCT c.Code) AS children
RETURN COLLECT(children) AS Children_Nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return a row for each `p.Code`, along with a list of the codes of its descendants:

```
MATCH (p:xyz)-[:children*]->(c:xyz)
WHERE p.Code IN [100, 200]
RETURN p.Code AS pCode, COLLECT(DISTINCT c.Code) AS descendantCodes
```

Comment: Hello, this gives me a (no changes, no records).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. If someone needs, they can refer the below answer. I tweaked the given query. Kindly respond if they have a better solution to my problem.

```
MATCH path = (p:xyz)-[:children *]->(c:xyz) WHERE p.Code IN [100, 200]
WITH 
COLLECT(path) as paths, COLLECT (c) + p AS all UNWIND all as p
MATCH (p)-[:children]->(c) CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths,true, {nodes: {xyz: 
['Code','Name']}}) yield  value as hierarchy RETURN hierarchy,collect(distinct c.Code) 
as code_list
```

But when i don't use

```
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths,true, {nodes: {xyz: 
['Code','Name']}}) yield  value as hierarchy
```

And just

```
MATCH path = (p:xyz)-[:children *]->(c:xyz)WHERE p.Code IN 
[100,200] WITH COLLECT(path) as paths, COLLECT (c) + p AS all UNWIND all as p 
MATCH (p)-[:children]->(c) CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths,true, {nodes: 
{xyz: ['Code','Name']}}) yield  value as hierarchy RETURN 
hierarchy,collect(distinct c.Code) as code_list
```

The output i get again is a collated list rather than a segregated one.